# Schema.org: How to define a product with variations

Tags: schema.org

I have a shop and I'm trying to use http://www.schema.org/Product to give more data to the searchengines. I have the following problem:
I have a product (lets say a shoe) with different variations (= different sizes, colors and so on). Should I define a http://www.schema.org/Product for every variation? In the shop-software this is modelled having a "parent-product" with "child-products".

Comment: Has each variation its own URL? If not, are *all* variations shown on the same page, or is only *one* variation shown (depending on selected value etc.)?

Comment: Ah, sorry: All variations are shown on the same page.

Answer (score 2):

You should use an own `Product` item for each variation, otherwise you could not use properties like [`color`](http://schema.org/color).

Here is *one* `Product` with two colors (e.g., striped):

```html
<article typeof="schema:Product">
  <!-- a red and black striped pair of shoes -->
  <span property="schema:color">Red</span>
  <span property="schema:color">Black</span>
</article>
```

Here are two `Products`, each having *one* color:

```html
<article typeof="schema:Product">
  <!-- red pair of shoes -->
  <span property="schema:color">Red</span>
</article>

<article typeof="schema:Product">
  <!-- black pair of shoes -->
  <span property="schema:color">Black</span>
</article>
```

Comment: I’m not experienced in this domain, so I’m not sure if it’s relevant for your case, but also have a look at [`ProductModel`](http://schema.org/ProductModel) and [`SomeProducts`](http://schema.org/SomeProducts).